# Como unir dos o más querys e imprimir de manera vertical con encabezados entre registros?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Buen día y gracias de antemano en lo que puedan ayudarme.

Estoy ejecutando 3 consultas en ORACLE SQL (3 sets de datos diferentes), necesito hacer un `UNION` de los 3 querys pero quiero que cada uno se muestre con sus respectivos encabezados.

Lo que quiero lograr básicamente es imprimir 3 reportes en uno solo, es decir, mostrar los registros de cada set de datos de manera vertical con sus respectivos encabezados, el resultado esperado sería algo mas o menos así:

```
|TITULO_1|TITULO_2|TITULO_3|
|SetData1|SetData1|SetData1|
|SetData1|SetData1|SetData1|
|SetData1|SetData1|SetData1|
|TITULO_1|TITULO_2|TITULO_3|
|SetData2|SetData2|SetData2|
|SetData2|SetData2|SetData2|
|SetData2|SetData2|SetData2|
|SetData2|SetData2|SetData2|
|SetData2|SetData2|SetData2|
|TITULO_1|TITULO_2|TITULO_3|
|SetData3|SetData3|SetData3|
|SetData3|SetData3|SetData3|
|SetData3|SetData3|SetData3|
```

---

**Nota:** Actualmente el `UNION` que tengo es en síntesis algo así:

```
SELECT T1.CAMPO1, T1.CAMPO2, T1.CAMPO3 FROM TABLA1 AS T1
UNION
SELECT T2.CAMPO1, T2.CAMPO2, T2.CAMPO3 FROM TABLA2 AS T2
UNION
SELECT T3.CAMPO1, T3.CAMPO2, T3.CAMPO3 FROM TABLA3 AS T3
```

Gracias por el apoyo y tomarse el tiempo para responder.
Feliz día..

Comment: Eso es algo que debes solucionar en el cliente, no en la base de datos. Solo necesitas una columna que identifique de donde salió cada fila.

Comment: A que te refieres, no comprendo lo que quieres decir..

Comment: ¿Quieres que los _títulos_ aparezcan intercalados entre los datos?

Comment: Sí, correcto así tal cual como el ejemplo que relacioné de como espero que se imprima el resultado..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un CTE para intercalar las filas que te interesa. He añadido una columna llamada orden, para poder realizar el ordenamiento al final.

```
with
Datos as (
          select 0 Orden, 'TITULO_1' Campo1, 'TITULO_1' Campo2, 'TITULO_1' Campo3 from dual
union all select 1, T1.CAMPO1, T1.CAMPO2, T1.CAMPO3 FROM TABLA1 AS T1
union all select 2, 'TITULO_2', 'TITULO_2', 'TITULO_2' from dual
union all select 3, T2.CAMPO1, T2.CAMPO2, T2.CAMPO3 FROM TABLA2 AS T2
union all select 4, 'TITULO_3', 'TITULO_3', 'TITULO_3' from dual
union all select 5, T3.CAMPO1, T3.CAMPO2, T3.CAMPO3 FROM TABLA3 AS T3
)
select Campo1, Campo2, Campo3
  from Datos
 order by Orden;
```

He cambiado la operación `union`, que utilizas en la pregunta, por `union all`, dado que asumo que los registros siempre van a ser diferentes dentro de cada tabla y el campo orden los va a forzar a ser diferentes entre tablas, y `union` *perdería* tiempo tratando de eliminar registros duplicados, mientras que `union all` simplemente los va a unir todos.

Finalmente, asumo que los campos son de un tipo compatible con `char` o `varchar`. Si no lo son, habría que aplicar alguna transformación en las columnas para que la operación de `union all` sea posible.

Comment: En Oracle le llaman `subquery factoring` al CTE.

Comment: Gracias por el dato, hace tiempo no trabajo con el motor, pero mantengo la afición por él, y obviamente me voy oxidando, sobre todo, en la terminología. :)

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias @jachguate es bastante claro y me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 1):

Como bien te dice @Luis Cazares, eso es algo que debería hacer tu aplicación cliente (la que se comunica con la base de datos), no algo que debiera sacar la propia base de datos, por eso te recomienda que introduzcas una columna más que te diga de qué tabla viene, y así poder ordenarlas para mostrar en el aplicación cliente.

Dicho esto, si sigues queriendo que la base de datos devuelva eso, puedes hacer algo como:

```
SELECT "T1.CAMPO1", "T1.CAMPO2", "T1.CAMPO3"
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(T1.CAMPO1 AS VARCHAR(50)), CAST(T1.CAMPO2 AS VARCHAR(50), CAST(T1.CAMPO3 AS VARCHAR(50) FROM TABLA1 AS T1
UNION ALL
SELECT "T2.CAMPO1", "T2.CAMPO2", "T2.CAMPO3"
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(T2.CAMPO1 AS VARCHAR(50)), CAST(T2.CAMPO2 AS VARCHAR(50), CAST(T2.CAMPO3 AS VARCHAR(50) FROM TABLA2 AS T2
UNION ALL
SELECT "T3.CAMPO1", "T3.CAMPO2", "T3.CAMPO3"
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(T3.CAMPO1 AS VARCHAR(50)), CAST(T3.CAMPO2 AS VARCHAR(50), CAST(T3.CAMPO3 AS VARCHAR(50) FROM TABLA3 AS T3
```

EDITADO:Corrección de @gabi13 en su comentario.

Comment: Yo también había pensado ese planteamiento, pero si no me equivoco, el UNION no mantiene el orden de los registros. Sin embargo con UNION ALL creo que sí lo haría

Comment: Buen punto, eso es por que al fin y al cabo UNION destruye las repeticiones. Si entre las tres tablas hay elementos comunes, pasaría como dices.

Comment: @Hermes Muchas gracias por la aclaración y tu respuesta, esta forma me ha dado luz para lograr el resultado esperado. Gracias